# Current project build configuration in SPM package's package.swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am building an SPM package repository to distribute my XCFrameworks (built using Flutter CLI), and I want to conditionally set the paths for these binary targets based on the build configuration (Debug or Release). I've tried using conditional compilation with `#if DEBUG` and `#else`, and I've set the `-DDEBUG` flag in my Xcode project's build settings for the Debug configuration, but it is seems like the `DEBUG` variable is not accessible in the package's `package.swift` file. Here is some code for reference.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "flutter_module_ios",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "flutter_module_ios",
            targets: ["App", "Flutter"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "App",
            path: {
                #if DEBUG
                return "Debug/App.xcframework"
                #else
                return "Release/App.xcframework"
                #endif
            }()
        ),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "Flutter",
            path: {
                #if DEBUG
                return "Debug/Flutter.xcframework"
                #else
                return "Release/Flutter.xcframework"
                #endif
            }()
        )
    ]
)
```

Is there a step I might be missing, or is there an alternative approach I should consider to achieve this conditional path setting for binary targets in Swift Package Manager?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!